# What is inside a Docker Ubuntu Image if Docker doesn't encapsulate an OS?

Tags: docker

I'm starting a new Django Project using Docker.  I'm confused about the existence of the Ubuntu Docker image which is mentioned in many tutorials as well as being one of the most popular images in the Docker Repo.

I thought Docker is a containerization system built ON TOP of the OS, so why is there an Ubuntu Docker Image?  Perhaps a common use scenario on when/who would use this would help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a Linux distro you normally get:

- A bootloader which loads a kernel
- A kernel which manages the system and loads an init system
- An `init` system that sets up and runs everything else
- Everything else

Docker itself replaces most of the `init` system.
Docker images replace "Everything else", which can still be a large portion of any normal distro.

An Ubuntu image contains the minimal set of Ubuntu binaries and shared libraries compiled with the Ubuntu build tools to run a shell, do some normal linuxy things and use the `apt` package manager.

A Centos image does the same with Centos binaries, shared libraries and the  `yum` package manager. etc.

A Docker image doesn't need to be a complete distribution. You can run a [single statically compiled binary](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/07/osx-static-golang-binaries-with-docker/) in a container and you only need that binary in the image, nothing else.

The [busybox](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/) image is a good example of building a largely normal Linux environment from a single static binary.

### The Kernel

All containers share the one host kernel. The container is separated from the rest of the system using kernel cgroups and namespaces. To anything running in the container, this appears to be it's own system.

All flavours of Linux don't use the exact same kernel but the [kernel interfaces are largely compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_interfaces) which allows the portability of Docker images. Docker itself requires a 3.10+ kernel to be able to run which narrows the range of kernel possibilities.

It's possible to have some esoteric software that requires some esoteric kernel feature to be compiled in, that wouldn't run across different Docker hosts. That's pretty rare and usually identifiable as it would often require a custom kernel compile or kernel modules to get said software working in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It is the other way around -- Docker really is 'just a process on steroids'.

The question then is: "which" process.  Having Docker containers for each of the different Ubuntu releases allows you to, for example, tests with the different Django versions shipped with each.

Illustration using the Ubuntu images I have here and `bash --version`:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:trusty bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:vivid bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:wily bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:xenial bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$
```

Comment: This is extremely confusing to me.  So you can run a Django project in different containers (for each version of Ubuntu), but how is that possible if the container doesn't hold the OS?

Comment: Read some Docker docs. In essence, there is either a very thin 'shim' providing Linux services (on Windows and OS X) or it is Linux directly. After that it is (somewhat recent) Linux features.  Here is an older intro article: http://www.zdnet.com/article/what-is-docker-and-why-is-it-so-darn-popular/ -- and there are literally thousands others. Read some, it is worth it. Docker is _very_ useful.

Comment: The "very thin shim" is a virtual machine running Linux.

Comment: In the old Docker setup, yes. New Docker 1.12 apparently does better. I wouldn't know as I use Docker on Linux where no shim is needed.

Comment: It's still a virtual machine, just packaged better. Docker for Mac moved to using a bhyve based hypervisor. Docker for Windows moved to HyperV. They are a bit more "native" than managing VirtualBox

Comment: What is your point? What I said still holds, and you just argue minute details largely irrelevant given  the newbie nature of the OP question.

Comment: Just noting that linux containers on osx and windows run in a complete Linux VM.

Comment: They're not using something like that new Windows Linux subsystem that provides API translation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own image from scratch. Literally your Dockerfile would start like this

```
FROM: scratch
...
```

but then everything that is needed to run your program needs to be added to the image. That's why it's more typical to start from a **lightweight** base linux image like [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) (very small at just 5MB) or [Debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/)/[Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) (126MB) that already have base tools/services needed by your app. You want to try to keep your final image small.

Comment: The base Ubuntu image is ~ 125MB, the same as Debian.

Comment: @Matt You're correct. I had the Golang base image in mind. Ubuntu has slimmed down also since 14.04. I'll update the answer.