# openssl version for Docker container

Tags: docker, openssl

Docker use own opensll or in relation of installed opensll on host machine? If it build a container with a particular version of openssl, the communcation is due it with this version?

Comment: See also [What is inside a Docker Ubuntu Image if Docker doesn't encapsulate an OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39237415/685806)

Answer (score 1):

Containers use the OS kernel on the host, but everything else (like openssl libraries) is encapsulated in the container. So a container will use the openssl installed in the container.

If your application uses openssl, openssl needs to be installed in the container. Your application can't access the host's openssl.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a container you can specify which version of OpenSSL (or any other library) you want to include within the container. This allows you to control the environment in which your application runs, ensuring that it has the required dependencies.

Docker containers are isolated from the host system and other containers. This isolation means that the version of OpenSSL installed within the container is independent of the host machine's OpenSSL installation.